# Using Python how can I have multiple class instances with their own objects as members?

Tags: python, class, object, instance

I am trying to have two objects of the same class have their own object as a member...when I call a function of their individual classes, that function is being called from both top-objects...

like this...

```
class Operation(threading._Timer):
    def __init__(self):
        threading._Timer.__init__(self)
    def cancel(self):
        self.finished.set()

class Manager():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ops = Operation()
    def stop(self):
        self.ops.cancel()

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ClassManager = Manager()

instance1 = A()
instance2 = A()

instance1.ClassManager.stop()
```

#

When I call `instance1.ClassManager.stop()`, it also stops the instance2's Manager.Operation....

I've looked around and only found that if your class has `__init__(self):` with its members defined with the `self` tag, they should be individualized for that particular instance of the class...

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `self.ClassManager = Manager`, rather than just getting the return value of `Manager`. You've done `Manager()` instead.

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't run at all (`_Timer` has two required arguments). What code are you actually running?

Comment: Can you please post the actual code that doesn't work, because `threading._Timer.__init__(self)`  cannot execute, because `_Timer.__init__()` requires at least two additional arguments. And why are you using `_Timer` instead of `Timer`?

Comment: is it really supposed to be self.ClassManager = Manager   ? even if you have the __init__ method?....the real code is very long, this was as simple as I could explain it